# Was the BeamRecord type removed from Apache Beam?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I'm working on an Apache Beam project and have found usage of the `BeamRecord` type in other projects. I'm unable to import this type using the latest version of the Java SDK (2.14.0) and am only able to access it when downgrading to version 2.3.0. I checked the [API documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/BeamRecord.html) and there is no indication that this type has been deprecated. Is the API documentation out of date? If so, which type should be used instead?

Comment: It was tagged @Experimental: "Signifies that a public API (public class, method or field) is subject to incompatible changes, or even removal, in a future release." So I guess that's what happened. (Sorry, I don't know of any replacement etc - I haven't used Beam myself.)

Comment: Interesting - that seems to be the case. I would have expected that it would be marked as "removed" in some way other than the potential indication of such using the @Experimental annotation.

Comment: I'd have expected to see it in the release notes, but I couldn't see anything.

Comment: That was definitely a miss from Beam release process. And it probably still can happen, I don't think that in practice there is an actual adopted approach in the community. Here is a relevant recent thread discussing potential ways of dealing with `@Experimental`: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/302bd51c77feb5c9ce39882316d391535a0fc92e7608a623d9139160@<dev.beam.apache.org> . Feel free to bring this up on the dev@beam.apache.org mail or user@beam.apache.org lists, this is a valuable feedback.

Comment: Correct link: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/302bd51c77feb5c9ce39882316d391535a0fc92e7608a623d9139160@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in Beam [Row](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.14.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/Row.html), which replaced BeamRecord.

You are correct, there's no mention of it in the release notes.

This is the [commit](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/c4ac00a7ac2fd1123e22f209be1d92c42ef56130#diff-9f726b9190d98db2135180b68112f274) that migrated to BeamRecord to Row.  It's still annotated `@Experimental`, but it's become one of the key element types in Beam, used with the Beam SQL APIs and is integrated with a number of IOs.

Comment: This is correct. `BeamRecord` was renamed to `Row` and migrated from SQL-specific notion to one of the core Beam classes. It is done as part of the wider effort to introduce schemas of the data elements to all aspects of Beam, not just SQL. Renaming/moving some of the core classes was one of the first steps.

Comment: BTW, `RowType` also got renamed to `Schema` since then.